# Mozilla SOPS & Azure Key Vault define `.sops.yaml`

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, mozilla-sops

I can't find the example of how to use Azure Keyvault with Mozilla SOPS in `.sops.yaml`.
All examples I saw in the WEB and provided here https://github.com/mozilla/sops#211using-sopsyaml-conf-to-select-kmspgp-for-new-files for AWS. Anyone saw Azure Key Vault example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Use `azure_keyvault` to configure AKV in `.sops.yaml`.

---

The official documentation lacks a clear description for that and actually can be a bit misleading. While the section [Using .sops.yaml conf to select KMS/PGP for new files](https://github.com/mozilla/sops#211using-sopsyaml-conf-to-select-kmspgp-for-new-files) shows the `--gcp-kms` flag being mapped to `gcp_kms` in the `.sops.yaml` file, the `--azure-kv` flag doesn't map to `azure_kv`, but instead `azure_keyvault`.

This specific detail can be found in the [source code](https://github.com/mozilla/sops/blob/8c8d780abb1bbc767ee0452ff352dd2ac1148392/config/config.go#L69).

Credits to [@feniix](https://github.com/feniix) who pointed this out in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/mozilla/sops/issues/436#issuecomment-470346507).